# python::how to return Mock variable value?

Tags: python, mysql, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

```
 def m():
   cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
   cursor = cnx.cursor()
   cnx.database = database_name
   cursor.execute('''SELECT COUNT(1) FROM URLlookup where malicious = '{0}' '''.format(new_URL))
   Malware = cursor.fetchone()[0]
   if Malware:
     do something
   else:
      do something
```

This i  basic code to find values from database.If value exists then Malware =True otherwise False

I am writing a unit test by using Mock library and mocked the Mysql connection but not able to return value True or False bool for Malware.

```
  with patch ('mysql.connector.connect') as mock_db:
    connection = mock_db.return_value
    cursor = connection.cursor.return_value
```

After ward how to return True or False for "Malware" so that IF else statement can executed accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

You need to mock `cursor.fetchone` to return a tuple of a single number.
Then call `m()` then check whether expected thing happened.

```
with patch ('mysql.connector.connect') as mock_db:
    connection = mock_db.return_value
    cursor = connection.cursor.return_value
    cursor.fetchone.return_value = (1,)  # or (0,)    # <-----
    # TODO  call m()
    # TODO  assert that something is done or not
```